# How to re-sort a structure using byte ordering lexicographically?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Developing with an API, I have a structure in ColdFusion. I need to re-sort the structure using byte ordering lexicographically.

"Sort the parameters by name lexicographically [sic] (byte ordering, the standard sorting, not natural or case insensitive). If the parameters have the same name, then sort by the value."

Taking a structure in ColdFusion 9, how can I reorder it to comply with the above? JAVA Lib?

Thanks

Comment: Does "lexographically" mean lexicographically?

Comment: actually they misspell it too, quote pasted from the API site. http://pic.photobucket.com/dev_help/WebHelpPublic/Content/Getting%20Started/Consumer%20Authentication.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to post this as a separate answer, because I believe my first one is incorrect... Let's try this one instead:

```
<cfset myStruct = structNew() />
<cfset mystruct["Apple"] = 1 />
<cfset mystruct["Banana"] = 2 />
<cfset mystruct["car"] = 5 />
<cfset mystruct["Tomato"] = 3 />
<cfset mystruct["aardvark"] = 4 />

<cfset Keys = StructKeyArray(myStruct) />
<cfset ArraySort(Keys, "textnocase") />

<cfdump var="#Keys#">
```

That will give you an array of keys sorted lexicographically, ignoring all casing. The `StructSort` function was sorting on the key values, not the key names.

Comment: Right, I finally get it now. My own definition of lexicographically was a little wrong. Even tho I quoted the API I did not understand it fully nor what they meant by lexicographically. Done a little Googling, tried with new data and using java.util.TreeMap failed after added more data. I still have to some additional sorting on the values, but I can work on this. Really do appreciate the help guys.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for my confusion, but aren't lexicographic sorting and natural sorting (at least with Java Strings) the same thing? If so, take a look at the Java TreeMap and see if this works the way you want it to.

```
<cfset myStruct = structNew() />
<cfset mystruct["Apple"] = 1 />
<cfset mystruct["Banana"] = 2 />
<cfset mystruct["car"] = 5 />
<cfset mystruct["Tomato"] = 3 />
<cfset mystruct["aardvark"] = 4 />


<cfset myMap = createObject("java","java.util.TreeMap").init(myStruct) />

<cfdump var="#myMap#">
```

Comment: humm... their quote: maybe they have this wrong.... http://pic.photobucket.com/dev_help/WebHelpPublic/Content/Getting%20Started/Consumer%20Authentication.htm

Comment: I appears you are right Jason, works like a charm. It's was their documentation that confused me. Just tested "java","java.util.TreeMap" accross CF8 and CF9 versions result order matches in both versions too! Cool.

Comment: Isn't lexicographic sorting supposed to ignore casing? If so, then the TreeMap returns them in the wrong order, with all Upper case words first, and then lower case words. I just tested my StructSort, and it returns the same, but still not in the right order :/. But I guess if you have it working the way you want, then that answers your question :)

Comment: lexicographic is a "alias" for ascii sort from what I have read Jason.  Lexicographic z1.doc z10.doc z100.doc z11.doc  z12.doc    -- where Natural z1.doc  z2.doc

Comment: Think Dan I jumped the Gun, I have it working now but only because of the data I am sending with java.util.TreeMap, but as you said not the correct order. oops.

Answer (score 2):

You can't technically sort a structure, and guarantee that the structure will maintain it's order. ColdFusion has a bad habit of arbitrarily (at least as far as I can tell) reordering structures when you add/remove nodes.

You can, however, get a list of sorted keys, which you can then use to loop through your struct. Use the [StructSort](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_s_30.html) method to get an array of sorted key names. You can specify the sort order as `textnocase` to get your lexicographic order (disregards all casing).

You would then need to do some additional sorting to get them by value after that... If you want more detail, you'll be better off posting some code you've already tried that's not quite working.

Comment: I am happy with that, it gives me something to look at thanks Dan.

Comment: @Dan - Re: *"reordering structures when you add/remove nodes"* CF structures do not guarantee any specific order. For that you need to use a different type of `Map` object, such as the one Jason showed. (If you really wanted a sorted structure that is) http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html